# Problems installing scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, pip, package, python-packaging

I was installing scikit-learn python module using pip, due to some reasons the installations was not completed, I tried to reinstall the package, but then it shows this error:

*pip can't proceed with requirement 'scikit-learn' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.
Storing debug log for failure in /home/yash/.pip/pip.log*

There's no module created for scikit-learn in my python dist-packages folder, so that I can delete and re-install.

Comment: Could you put that debug log here somehow, maybe using cloud storage?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how check the logs. could you tell me how to do that ? @АндрейЧереваткин

Comment: Thi is the log file pip.log file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mct4yoshgjeb6rb/log.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

The log says:

```
pip can't proceed with requirement 'scikit-learn' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn
```

I'm sure what you need is to delete that directory and try installing again

Actually, you posted that phrase in your question, and I didn't realy need to ask for the log :)

By the way, why did your first installation fail?

Comment: but I'm not able to locate the directory, I've searched in the tmp folder, but there's no /pip_build_root/ directory. can you please help

Comment: Try $ sudo rm -r /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-learn  If there are no errors, you're done deleting that directory.

Comment: Thanks! worked. my upvote not counted, I have <15 repo.

Comment: You're welcome :) Some directories in Linux are invisible for non-root user